# Why is ::before pseudo element taking up room in flexbox?

Tags: css, flexbox

I have a simple example [here](https://jsfiddle.net/fret2nsk/5/) where I am setting `::before` to provide a shade to the background. I do this on an element that is `display: flex`. I then set one of the flex items to `flex: 1`. Two things happen I don't like:

1. The `flex:1` is ignored because the `::before` takes up too much room, and
2. The `::before` is not the full width as I would expect given `width: 100%`

Why is this happening? Is there a way to tell flex to ignore `::before` & `::after`?

Here is some screen shots. I would expect the width here to be 100% (200px)

[image]

And I would expect this `flex:1` to fill the rest of the screen.

[image]

```css
.test {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
}

.first {
  background-color: green;
}

.second {
  background-color: grey;
  flex: 1;
}

body {
  background-color: purple;
}

.test::before {
  background-color: yellow;
  content: "";
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  opacity: 0.04;
}
```

```html
<div class="test">
  <div class="first">
    &nbsp;
  </div>
  <div class="second">
    &nbsp;
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first thing to know is that pseudo elements applied to a flex container become flex items ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Firefox/Releases/23#CSS)).

Therefore, your container (`.test`) has three flex items, with the `::before` being just another sibling.

> Is there a way to tell flex to ignore `::before` & `::after`?

Yes. Remove the pseudo element from the document flow. Use absolute positioning.

> I would expect the width here to be 100% (200px).

Once the `::before` is removed from the document flow, it will be free to expand across the container.

```css
.test {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
  position: relative;  /* new */
}

.test::before {
  position: absolute; /* new */
  background-color: yellow;
  content: "";
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 0.04;
}

.first {
  background-color: green;
}

.second {
  background-color: grey;
  flex: 1;
}

body {
  background-color: purple;
}
```

```html
<div class="test">
  <div class="first">
    &nbsp;
  </div>
  <div class="second">
    &nbsp;
  </div>
</div>
```

More information: [Support `::before`, `::after` as flex items](https://bugzilla.mozil]la.org/show_bug.cgi?id=867454), Bugzilla

Comment: Is there some kind of pseudo element that comes before the element (positioned same (relative(?))) That isn't included? Can we get some more docs stating this behavior?

Comment: Too quick for me on the last part :-), Although maybe some more docs on the logic of this behavior would be nice.

Comment: The information provided at MDN, which I linked to, contains a link to the full bug report.

Comment: I was hoping relative would work but nope. I lose height and width when I do absolute which I suppose I could control in code. Uggghhh just hoping it was easier thanks again!

Comment: Relative won't remove the item from the document flow, so it's not helpful in this case.

Comment: BTW here is a working version https://jsfiddle.net/yteh56sa/11/